# Javascript/jquery Table Filtering Merge

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap tada filter with JSON export with pdf, excel.
anyone can help me with this?>

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var $table = $('#edit_table')
  $(function() {
    $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
      $table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
        exportDataType: $(this).val(),
        exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel', 'pdf'],
        columns: [
          {
            field: 'state',
            checkbox: true,
            visible: $(this).val() === 'selected'
          },
          {
            field: 'id_item',
            title: 'Batch Number'
          },
          {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'Product Name'
          },
          {
            field: 'quantity',
            title: 'Quantity'
          },
          {
            field: 'price',
            title: 'Price'
          },
          {
            field: 'type',
            title: 'Category'
          },
          {
            field: 'date',
            title: 'Date Stockout'
          }
        ]
      })
    }).trigger('change')
  })
</script>
```

And this the code i want to Merge with:

```
$(function() 
  {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable()
  }
  )
  
//Moment.JS Return Date Ranges
function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
    var dateArray = [];
    var currentDate = moment(startDate);
    var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
    while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
        dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
    }
    return dateArray;
}
 
  
  $('#ok').click( function() 
  { 

    var $table = $('#table')
    var from=$("input[type=date][name=date1]" ).val();
    var to=$("input[type=date][name=date2]" ).val();
    $table.bootstrapTable('filterBy',{ ETA: getDates(from,to)}) 
        
    
 
})
```

is that possible?

I am making a table with a Data range picker with Export at the same time.
But can construct it on my own. anyone can help me?

reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/06pg2wms/11/

Comment: i dont understand what you want...